# Nongeneral columns with read_excel using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I'm trying to read data from an excel file that has a date column, and a price column. The `read_excel` function in pandas doesn't seem to like that. I've been looking around for a way to convert them all to general beforehand, but I haven't seen anything.

Looking over the `read_excel` documentation it's not possible to do it directly through it. Is there a better method of reading an excel file to a dataframe than that, that will ignore the type of the column?

Comment: Does it work if you export the excel sheet as csv and use `read_csv` instead?

Comment: What error do you get? This should normally not be a problem.

Comment: Could you give a toy example (and share it online)